# ASP.NET MVC - Ajax.BeginForm Is there a way to specify protocol (http / https) without overriding the action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Html.BeginForm has an overload that allows you to specify the protocol to use.

Am I correct in saying that Ajax.BeginForm does not?

I'm currently working around by outputting the equivalent form html with a modified action, but this feels messy.

```
@{
    string actionStr = Config.EnableHttps ? Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { }, "https").UrlToUrlWithoutPort()
                                            :
                                            Url.Action("Action", "Controller", new { }, "http");
}

<form method="post" data-ajax-loading="#SomeGif" data-ajax="true" action="@actionStr">
```

Answer (score 1):

can you place a  `[RequireHttps]` attribute on the action method, requiring all calls to be https?  Or write a custom attribute that checks the config.enablehttps and requires it that way?